# Differences between Chrome and Firefox wrapping a column div

Tags: html, css

I have a layout defined through CSS that has three columns.  It displays correctly through Chrome, but in Firefox, the third (right) column wraps around to the bottom.  Am I defining the layout incorrectly?

```
<style type="text/css">
    .content {
        position: relative;
        border-top-width: 1px;
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 960px;
        margin-top: -1px;
    }

    .content-container {
        border: 0;
        position: relative;
        width: 960px;
        border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
        margin: auto;
    }

    .left-menu-container {
        width: 188px;
        padding: 0 20px 0 0;
        border: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        vertical-align: top;
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    .center-content-container {
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        min-height: 900px;
        width: 500px;
        border-left: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
        border-right: 1px solid #EBEBEB;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    }

    .center-content-subcontainer {
        padding: 0 0 0 5px;

    }

    .right-menu-container {
        vertical-align: top;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 260px;
        border: solid;
        position: relative;
    }

    .right-menu-subcontainer {
        margin: 16px 0 0 0;
    }   

    #slideshow {
        position:relative;
        height:250px;
        width: 250px;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }

</style>
```

**How can I get this to display correctly across browsers?**

```
<body>
<div class="content">
    <div class="content-container">
        <div class="left-menu-container"></div>

        <div class="center-content-container">
            <div class="center-content-subcontainer"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-menu-container">
            <div class="right-menu-subcontainer">
                <div id="slideshow" align="center">
                    <img src="" alt="Slideshow" title="Slideshow" width="250" height="100">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


</body>
```

Comment: Code/style from above: http://jsfiddle.net/userdude/cTWuE/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In FF 5.x the box widths are this:

```
Left: 188 + 20 (width+ padding)
Center: 500 + 1 + 1 (width + L & R borders)
Right: 260 + 3 + 3 (width + L & R borders)

Total: 976
```

Firebug's Layout Inspector is your friend here.

Comment: @Ed:  IMHO, this is the heart of the matter.  You have 976 pixels crammed into a 960 pixel wide container.

Comment: ah.  how did I miss the padding?!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is with this line of CSS:

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

What version of Firefox are you using? Because even as late as version 4 (possibly later, I'm not sure), Firefox only supports `-moz-box-sizing`. And if Firefox isn't changing its box-sizing, then that means it thinks you're trying to stick 968px worth of content into 960px worth of space.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your left-container:

```
.left-menu-container {

    width: 188px;
    padding: 0 20px 0 0;
    border: 0;

    -moz-box-sizing:    border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing:         border-box;

    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Probably worth a read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-sizing